# possibility of concurrent p2p and AccessPoint modes in single wifi interface

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wireless-access-point, wifi-direct

Is it possible to setup one wifi interface in Access point mode and another virtual interface in p2p mode concurrently? If not why?

My device supports p2p and AP:
iw list shows this :
valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed, P2P-client } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-GO } <= 2,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1

I am able to run hostapd and wpa_supplicant. But when I start p2p_listen or p2p_find, Accesspoint becomes invisible. iw dev shows that AP is still Up.

And What is the meaning of the below line?
Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
I saw this at the end of iw list for my device. I am using TL_WN721N

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

From the valid interface combination, its clear that we could make a maximum of two interfaces(total <= 2), in which, in our case we will choose the second combination - (AP and P2P-GO). But take care of the restriction, channels <= 1. We should use the same hardware channel in both hostapd and wpa_supplicant.

setting channel in wpa_supplicant for p2p mode :

p2p_oper_channel=11 
(in hostapd.conf, the corresponding parameter is channel)

In some case, one more restriction will be there, ie BI must match. In that case, set beacon interval  to the same value in both hostapd.conf and wpa_supplicant.conf.

beacon_int=100

sometimes you need to specify the operation reg class also.

p2p_oper_reg_class=60